# Where to download a complete database of all GPS coordinates of Germany cities/towns?

Tags: gps, coordinates

I am looking for a MySQL, CSV or else database of all GPS coordinates of cities/towns in Germany. Is there a place where I can download this? I've been searching on almost every POI file websites but I can't find a place where I can just download a file with all GPS coordinates of German towns.

I know there is a site at http://earth-info.nga.mil where this information maybe is available, but the site seems to be down for days already so I am not even sure if it actually there at all.

Any suggestions? Maybe a mirror site or another site?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: just for the record: I found GeoLite. At least for those who need the centre location of cities using an integrated database. 


 check here: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Street Map (OSM) seems to be a useful resource for your needs. If you're working with a Garmin, here's a link for Germany's Garmin maps: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/All_in_one_Garmin_Map#Germany.

Since you asked about a database however, the [OSM Database](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Database) and/or [Import Data](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Catalogue) pages should be helpful.

I searched briefly on stackoverflow for [questions related to OSM](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=osm), but you'll probably have better luck since I wasn't certain what aspects of OSM you might be interested in.

---

Description of OSM from the [OSM Homepage](http://www.openstreetmap.org/):

> OpenStreetMap is a free editable map
>   of the whole world. It is made by
>   people like you.
>
> OpenStreetMap allows you to view, edit
>   and use geographical data in a
>   collaborative way from anywhere on
>   Earth.
>
> OpenStreetMap's hosting is kindly
>   supported by the UCL VR Centre and
>   bytemark. Other supporters of the
>   project are listed in the wiki.

Quoting the [OSM Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page):

> OpenStreetMap creates and provides
>   free geographic data such as street
>   maps to anyone who wants them. The
>   project was started because most maps
>   you think of as free actually have
>   legal or technical restrictions on
>   their use, holding back people from
>   using them in creative, productive, or
>   unexpected ways.